# Re-rendering react component after clicking Like button (with Redux)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have the following React component that shows all the users posts through the "renderPosts" method. Below it there's a like/unlike button on whether the currently logged in user has liked the post.

However, when I click on the like button, the component does not re-render in order for the "renderPosts" method to create an unlike button and the "like string" is modified as expected. Only when I go to another component and then come back to this component does the unlike button display and vice versa.

Is there anyway that I could fix this with Redux in my app? I tried this.forceUpdate after the onClick event but still does not work...

Also I tried creating a new Reducer called "likers", according to robinsax which basically get the array of users who like a particular post and imported it as props into the component but got

```
"this.props.likers.includes(currentUser)" is not a function
```

When the app first gets to the main page (PostIndex), probably because this.props.likers is still an empty object returned from reducer

Here is the code for my action creator:

```
export function likePost(username,postId) {
    // body...
    const request = {
        username,
        postId
    }
    const post = axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/likePost`,request);
    return{
        type: LIKE_POST,
        payload: post
    }
}
export function unlikePost(username,postId){
    const request = {
        username,
        postId
    }
    const post = axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/unlikePost`,request);
    return{
        type: UNLIKE_POST,
        payload: post
    }
}
```

And this is my reducer:

```
import {LIKE_POST,UNLIKE_POST} from '../actions/index.js';

export default function(state = {},action){
    switch(action.type){
        case LIKE_POST:
            const likers = action.payload.data.likedBy;
            console.log(likers);
            return likers;
        case UNLIKE_POST:
            const unlikers = action.payload.data.likedBy;
            console.log(unlikers);
            return unlikers;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

I would really appreciate any help since I'm a beginner

```
import { fetchPosts } from "../actions/";
import { likePost } from "../actions/";
import { unlikePost } from "../actions/";
class PostsIndex extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchPosts();
    }
    renderPost() {
        const currentUser = Object.values(this.props.users)[0].username;
        return _.map(this.props.posts, post => {
            return (
                <li className="list-group-item">
                    <Link to={`/user/${post.username}`}>
                        Poster: {post.username}
                    </Link>
                    <br />
                    Created At: {post.createdAt}, near {post.location}
                    <br />
                    <Link to={`/posts/${post._id}`}>{post.title}</Link>
                    <br />
                    //error here, with this.props.likers being an 
                    //array
                    {!this.props.likers.includes(currentUser) ? (
                        <Button
                            onClick={() => this.props.likePost(currentUser,post._id)}
                            bsStyle="success"
                        >
                            Like
                        </Button>
                    ) : (
                        <Button
                            onClick={() => this.props.unlikePost(currentUser,post._id)}
                            bsStyle="warning"
                        >
                            Unlike
                        </Button>
                    )}{" "}
                    {post.likedBy.length === 1
                        ? `${post.likedBy[0]} likes this`
                        : `${post.likedBy.length} people like this`}
                </li>
            );
        });
    }
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        posts: state.posts,
        users: state.users,
        likers: state.likers
    };
}
}
```

Comment: Could you also add the reducer code for `likePost()`?

Comment: I just did. Thank you for suggestions

Comment: What is your state shape after like or unlike? Shape is the object structure.

Comment: What state are you talking about? If you are talking about the likers state, then it’s an array.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the like/unlike post functionality isn't causing anything in your `state` or `props` to change, so the component doesn't re-render.

You should change the data structure you're storing so that the value of `post.likedBy.includes(currentUser)` is included in one of those, or `forceUpdate()` the component after the `likePost` and `unlikePost` calls.

Please do it the first way so I can sleep at night. Having a component's `render()` be affected by things not in its `props` or `state` defeats the purpose of using `React`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use redux-thunk middleware in order to use async actions.
First, add redux-thunk while creating store like

```
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
const store = createStore(
   rootReducer,
   applyMiddleware(thunk)  
);
```

then change your method like this

```
export function likePost(username,postId) {
    return function(dispatch) {
        // body...
         const request = {
            username,
            postId
          }
         axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/likePost`,request)
          .then(res => {
              dispatch({
                 type: LIKE_POST,
                 payload: res
           });
      });
    }
}
```

and now in your component after mapStateToProps, define mapDispatchToProps,

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
       return {
           likePost: (currentUser,postId) => dispatch(likePost(currentUser, postId)),
           // same goes for "unlike" function
       }
 }

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PostsIndex);
```

Answer (score 2):

As noted in other answers, you need to use `redux-thunk` or `redux-saga` to make async calls that update you reducer. I personally prefer `redux-saga`. Here's is a basic implementation of React, Redux, and Redux-Saga.

Redux-Saga uses JavaScript [generator functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator) and [yield](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield) to accomplish the goal of handling async calls.

Below you'll see a lot of familiar React-Redux code, the key parts of Redux-Saga are as follows:

- `watchRequest` - A generator function that maps dispatch actions to generator functions
- `loadTodo` - A generator function called from `watchRequest` to `yield` a value from an async call and dispatch an action for the reducer
- `getTodoAPI` - A regular function that makes a `fetch` request
- `applyMiddleware` - from Redux is used to connect Redux-Saga with `createStore`

```js
const { applyMiddleware, createStore } = Redux;
const createSagaMiddleware = ReduxSaga.default;
const { put, call } = ReduxSaga.effects;
const { takeLatest } = ReduxSaga;
const { connect, Provider } = ReactRedux;

// API Call
const getTodoAPI = () => {
  return fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
    .then(response => {
      return response.json()
        .then(response =>  response);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      throw error;
    })
};

// Reducer
const userReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'LOAD_TODO_SUCCESS':
      return action.todo;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

// Sagas, which are generator functions
// Note: the asterix
function* loadTodo() {
  try {
    const todo = yield call(getTodoAPI);
    yield put({type: 'LOAD_TODO_SUCCESS', todo});
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
}

// Redux-Saga uses generator functions,
// which are basically watchers to wait for an action
function* watchRequest() {
  yield* takeLatest('LOAD_TODO_REQUEST', loadTodo);
}

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { data } = this.props;
      return (
        <div>
          <button onClick={() => this.props.getTodo()}>Load Data</button>
          {data ?
            <p>data: {JSON.stringify(data)}</p>
            : null
          }
        </div>
      )
    }
}
// Setup React-Redux and Connect Redux-Saga
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
const store = createStore(userReducer, applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware));
sagaMiddleware.run(watchRequest);

// Your regular React-Redux stuff
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({ data: state }); // Map the store's state to component's props
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({ getTodo: () => dispatch({type: 'LOAD_TODO_REQUEST'}) })  // wrap action creator with dispatch method
const RootComponent = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <RootComponent />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/babel-regenerator-runtime@6.3.13/runtime.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/4.0.1/redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/6.0.0/react-redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux-saga/0.16.2/redux-saga.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your action creator.

```
export function likePost(username,postId) {
    // body...
    const request = {
        username,
        postId
    }
    // this is an async call
    const post = axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/likePost`,request);
    // next line will execute before the above async call is returned
    return{
        type: LIKE_POST,
        payload: post
    }
}
```

Because of that your state is likely never updated and stays in the initial value.

You would need to use either `redux-thunk` or `redux-saga` to work with async actions.

Comment: You have any idea how would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

As they say use redux-thunk or redux-saga. If your new to redux I prefer redux-thunk because it's easy to learn than redux-saga. You can rewrite your code like this

```
export function likePost(username,postId) {
// body...
const request = {
    username,
    postId
}
const post = axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/likePost`,request);
return dispatch => {
    post.then(res => {
      dispatch(anotherAction) //it can be the action to update state
    });
}
```

}